# Вывод из нескольких столбцов

Tags: php, sql, веб-программирование

Проблема тривиальна, но нагуглить я её так и не смог, поэтому если подскажете в какую сторону смотреть буду очень благодарен. Сильно не пинайте, я  изучаю php 2 неделю.

**Дано**: Таблица в mssql 2005(старый старый сайт написанный еще на табличной верстке). Необходимо добавить 4 кнопки чтобы они выводили  4 разных сообщения в двух столбцах. Кнопки : Согласованно/несогласованно, Результат принят/не принят.
 Я добавил 6 новых столбов в бд с именами reconcile, reconcile_date, unreconcile. resul, result_date, unresult. На сайте **необходимо** вывести Согласованность объекта и результат. Я пытался написать код сам. Но что-то пошло не так, и значения не выводятся.

P.S Так же имеются дополнительные переменные типа времени и имени согласовывающего и принимающего результат.

Пример моего кода вот такой :

```
if (isset($d['reconcile'])) {
    $rec =  echo 'Согласованно' . $rtime . $d['rname'];
} else {
    if (isset($d['unreconcile'])) {
        $rec = echo 'Несогласованно' $rtime . $d['rname'];
    } else {
        $rec = echo '&nbsp';
    }
}
```

Comment: немного неверно скопировал, в первом if(isset( тоже есть $d это обычный запрос в бд и fetch_assoc

Comment: Если неверно, то [поправте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/820220/edit) .

Answer (score 0):

Здесь точка пропущена:

```
$rec =  echo 'Несогласованно' $rtime . $d['rname'];
```

с точкой:

```
$rec =  echo 'Несогласованно' . $rtime . $d['rname'];
```